# "How to fix the problem of installation of the UiPath each and everytime ?"

Tags: uipath-studio

I had installed the UiPath and accept the free license. But, once if we close the tool and again try to open it then every time it opens the installation screen and asks for a license. 
Please give the solution of this issue.
Thanks.

Expected Result: Once the UiPath is installed then able to easily open it.

Actual Result: Every time needs to install the UiPath tool.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no matter what version you have, you have to activate it. Studio activated once will not ask for it anymore, for community edition you can do it here:
https://www.uipath.com/renew-community-license

Comment: Sure. I will try by this. Thanks.